Bare minimum implementation of Dallas 1-wire DS2401 slave for ATtiny9
I have completed my project and have it operating reliably on an Arduino nano -
Arduino Sketch here.
The target device is an ATtiny9.
I used this project to make the jump from Arduino IDE to Microchip studio and C programming.  Any and all comments are very much appreciated.
#define F_CPU 8000000UL                                         //Internal 8MHz Ocilator, /1 prescale = 8MHz clkCPU
#include "avr/io.h"
#include "util/delay.h"
#define PB0pin 1                                                //PB0 = Pin D8 for a nano  = B0000001
#define PB0m 0                                                  // no shift needed for PB0 mask

uint8_t ESN[] = {142, 0, 0, 27, 196, 100, 133, 1};              //64bit ROM contents
    
void waitForLow(void){
    while (PINB & PB0){
    }                                       //pause while PB0 is HIGH
}

void waitForHigh(void){
    while (!PINB & PB0){
    }                                       //pause while PB0 is LOW
}

void pullLowForZero(void){
    DDRB |= 1 << PB0m;                                          //PB0 set to OUTPUT and defaults to LOW beginning presence pulse
    _delay_us(35);
    DDRB &= ~(1 << PB0m);                                       //Reset PB0 to input high impedance so it doesnt hold high and can be used as input again
    _delay_us(5);
}

void searchRom(void){
    for (int i=7; i>=0; i--){                                   //Index for ESN[] bytes
        for (uint8_t mask = 1; mask>0; mask <<= 1){             //Index mask for bits out of selected ESN[] byte
            waitForLow();                                       //Wait for read pulse from master                             DS2401 Tx BitN
            if(ESN[i] & mask){                                  //If current bit is a one
                _delay_us(10);                                  //Do not pull low for Zero Wait for read pulse to pass
            }                                     
            else{                                               //It current bit wasnt a one
                pullLowForZero();
            }
            waitForLow();                                       //Wait for read pulse from master                             DS2401 Tx !BitN
            if(ESN[i] & mask){                                  //If current bit is a one
                pullLowForZero();                               //Send a Zero since were in the complement stage
            }                                  
            else{
                _delay_us(10);                                  //Do not pull low for Zero Wait for read pulse to pass
            }                                     
            waitForLow();                                       //Absorbing the Master Tx BitN                                Master Tx BitN device select
            waitForHigh();                                      //Incompatible with multiple 1-wire units now
        }
    }
}
    
int main(void){
    //CLKMSR = 0;                                               //Defaults to 0 for internal 8mhz occilator?
    CLKPSR = 0;                                                 //Set /1 prescaler for max CPU speed on internal oscillator, Source clock = 8Mhz clkCPU = 8Mhz
    TCCR0B = 0x2;                                               //Set /8 prescaler timer0 now counts 1us per tick            Timer0 clock = 1Mhz
        
    while (1) 
    {
// RESET PULSE DETECTION -- Reset Pulse nominal 480us will overflow 8-bit counter, need to use 16-bit -----------  Uses PB0 as input
        while (1){                                              //scanning for the reset pulse
            if (!PINB & PB0){                                   //when target pin goes LOW begin timing LOW pulse
                TCNT0 = 0;                                      //reset Timer0 to 0, 8Mhz Attiny with /8 prescale will be 1us per tick
                uint16_t time0 = TCNT0;                         //timestamp of detected LOW, TCNT0 atomic reads the high/low bytes of the timer, 65ms overflow
                waitForHigh();
                if (TCNT0 - time0 > 200){                       //if pulse was longer than 200uS 8mhz /8 prescale 1 tick = 1us nominal ~480us
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        _delay_us(50);                                          //Delay between end of reset pulse and presence pulse

// PRESENSE PULSE RESPONSE -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Uses PB0 as output
        DDRB |= 1 << PB0m;                                      //PB0 set to OUTPUT and defaults to LOW beginning presence pulse
        _delay_us(150);
        DDRB &= ~(1 << PB0m);                                   //Reset PB0 to input high impedance so it doesnt hold high and can be used as input again
        _delay_us(150);

// COMMAND BYTE READ -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Uses PB0 as input
        uint8_t romCommand = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){                            //index counter for building the command byte
            waitForLow();
            TCNT0 = 0;
            waitForHigh();
            if (TCNT0L < 40){                                   //1us per tick, Master holds low for 65us for a 0, so less than 40us is going to be a 1 (10us nominal)
                romCommand |= 1 << i;                           //Below threshold, set i index bit of command byte
            }
        }

// COMMAND SWITCH ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if(romCommand == 0xF0){                                 //0xF0 SearchRom,  0X33 ReadRom, 0x0F legacy ReadRom for the 2400
            searchRom();
        }
    }
// END OF LOOP -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}

One specific question I have:

Do I have proper setup of the ATtiny9 for 8MHz system clock and 1MHz timer0?

This code is also available on GitHub.

Strongly suggest you adopt a consistent indentation and brace style throughout your code.

Thanks @Chris, not sure how i missed those indentations, Should be all H&R now.
I had done the different style on the waitforlow/high on purpose since the while loop contained nothing. I take it its bad form to mix styles for any reason?

You spend more time reading code than writing it. Be nice to yourself.

Comments
I have several comments about the code comments.
I see that you spent great effort to carefully align the end-of-line comments;
however, there is too much wasted horizontal whitespace.  This requires either
a very wide screen or a lot of horizontal scrolling.  In any case, it detracts
from understanding the code.
On the one hand, it is great that you added ample comments.  On the other hand,
this is likely an indication that you could have chosen more descriptive names
for functions and variables.
Instead of having an end-of-line comment on several consecutive lines, it
would be preferable to write the comments inside a block comment (/**/) above the lines
(or function).  This lends itself better to writing complete sentences,
rather than disjoint phrases.  It is easier to maintain free-flowing text
than your rigidly aligned comments.
Remove commented-out code to reduce clutter:
//CLKMSR = 0;   //Defaults to 0 for internal 8mhz occilator?

The comments in the main while loop should all be indented
to the indent level of the code.  Change:
    while (1) 
    {
// RESET PULSE DETECTION -- Reset Pulse nominal 480us will overflow 8-bit counter, need to use 16-bit -----------  Uses PB0 as input
        while (1){                                              //scanning for the reset pulse

to:
    while (1) 
    {
        // RESET PULSE DETECTION -- Reset Pulse nominal 480us will overflow 8-bit counter, need to use 16-bit -----------  Uses PB0 as input
        while (1){                                              //scanning for the reset pulse

Naming
It is always helpful to create macros like these:
#define PB0pin 1
#define PB0m 0

However, the code would be easier to understand with longer, more meaningful names.
Consider the following line, which is repeated a few times:
waitForLow();   //Wait for read pulse from master

It is good that you create a function that you call several times.
However, you could have avoided the comment had you given the function
a more meaningful name.  For example, it could have been named:
wait_for_read_pulse();

In that case, you can remove the redundant comment.  The advantage is that
you no longer need to update the comment if the code is ever updated.
We often forget to update comments after the code is modified, and this
leaves behind comments which are wrong, leading to confusion for code
maintainers.
This function name:
_delay_us(5);

would be better without the leading underscore:
delay_us(5);

DRY
There are 2 functions with very similar names and code:
void waitForLow(void){
void waitForHigh(void){

It would be beneficial to combine these into a single function
where you can pass in an argument, where the argument determines
the behavior.
Also, the comments in the function seem to contradict the function names
(high vs. low, and vice versa):
void waitForLow(void){  //pause while PB0 is HIGH
void waitForHigh(void){ //pause while PB0 is LOW

This is confusing, but the confusion can be eliminated with the argument:
waitForPB0(1);
waitForPB0(0);

A function name like this now allows the user know what we are waiting for.

The waitForLow() and waitForHigh() comments look correct to me - we wait whilst the input is not in the state we want.

@TobySpeight: That may be so.  However, the comment mentions PB0, but the code shows PB0 in both functions, and it is not negated in either.  PINB is negated.  Maybe the comment should mention PINB instead of PB0.  My main point is that it seems confusing to me, and it warrants attention.

@toolic PINB is the Pin INput register B and PB0 is the name of a physical pin in that register. Thats why the comment is based on PB0. Per Tobys other answer PINB being negated is incorrect, i should have negated the entire while test.
THANK YOU for your well written comments they were very insightful.
I realized the comments i did NOT have indented to align with code is because i was breaking the main loop into functional sections that should each be a function.
_delay_us() was from a library ill have to see if it compiles without the leading underscore
Thanks for taking the time.

This busy-wait loop looks suspect:
void waitForHigh(void){
    while (!PINB & PB0){
    }
}

I don't think we really want to be taking the logical negation of PINB - that makes no sense for a bit-flags register, and even less sense when followed by a bitwise AND operation.  I suspect that what was intended is !(PINB & PB0).  Or perhaps ~PINB & PB0.

Good catch, that was my intention. Your method also saves 3 ASM instructions
Functionally would the result be the same? Inverting the register before masking vs inverting the masked bit?

Inverting the register would be ~PINB, not !PINB.
